# Rooting android via virtual windows 8 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: rooting, root-access

I want to root my sony xperia p android 4.1.2. I'm using ubuntu 12.04LTS and it seems uncomfortable to root my xperia via ubuntu. So i've installed windows 8 (32 bit) on virtual box. Is it will be safe to root my phone via virtual windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass the USB control of the device from the host to the guest, then it should be perfectly fine. This requires the closed-source version of virtual box. [Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41571/pass-through-usb-device-to-guest-using-virtualbox)